# Table Cleanup - Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have this raw data that I want cleaned and have already loaded it on the query editor. Screenshot of the data via the Query editor is attached.

Ideally, what I want to achieve is to have the 'Column 1' standardized and split into their own columns. First column would be the store number while the 2nd column would be the item description.

I've tried pivoting the columns and such but it does not yield the desired output. Also tried adding a couple of custom columns that would return the store number if the lenght of the available value on column 1 is less than 2. Then had it filled down. Worked fine. The problem is if I apply the same method on the description, the output of either filling it up or down would be incorrect

Comment: No screenshot attached - not that I can view them from work anyway. Just put some sample data into your question

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: Solved. I filled down column 1 first prior to creating a custom column for description. Instead of filling this down, I filled it up

Additional Edit: Sorry for those looking with the screenshot. I'm sure I attached it prior to posting the question.